# pandas calculate rolling_std of top N dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date      A
2015.1.1  10
2015.1.2  20
2015.1.3  30
2015.1.4  40
2015.1.5  50
2015.1.6  60
```

I need to caculate the std of top N rows, such as:

```
date      A  std
2015.1.1  10  std(10)
2015.1.2  20  std(10,20)
2015.1.3  30  std(10,20,30)
2015.1.4  40  std(10,20,30,40)
2015.1.5  50  std(10,20,30,40,50)
2015.1.6  60  std(10,20,30,40,50,60)
```

pd.rolling_std is used to do this, however, **how to change N dynamically?**

```
df[['A']].apply(lambda x:pd.rolling_std(x,N))
```

---

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 75 entries, 2015-04-16 to 2015-07-31
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    75 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 2.9+ KB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done by calling `apply` on the df like so:

```
In [29]:
def func(x):
    return df.iloc[:x.name + 1][x.index].std()
​
df['std'] = df[['A']].apply(func, axis=1)
df
Out[29]:
       date   A        std
0  2015.1.1  10        NaN
1  2015.1.2  20   7.071068
2  2015.1.3  30  10.000000
3  2015.1.4  40  12.909944
4  2015.1.5  50  15.811388
5  2015.1.6  60  18.708287
```

This uses double subscripts `[[]]` to call `apply` on a df with a single column, this allows you to pass param `axis=1` so you can call you function row-wise, you then have access to the index attribute, which is `name` and the column name attribute, which is `index`, this allows you to slice your df to calculate a rolling `std`.

You can add a window arg to `func` to modify the window as desired

**EDIT**

It looks like your index is a str, the following should work:

```
In [39]:
def func(x):
    return df.ix[:x.name ][x.index].std()
​
df['std'] = df[['A']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df

Out[39]:
           A        std
date                   
2015.1.1  10        NaN
2015.1.2  20   7.071068
2015.1.3  30  10.000000
2015.1.4  40  12.909944
2015.1.5  50  15.811388
2015.1.6  60  18.708287
```

Comment: what means `x.name + 1`

Comment: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"

Comment: `name` is the index attribute, can you post output from `df.info()` and edit this into your question, what is your index?

Comment: I have edit question. I need to calc column 'fluc_ic'

Comment: OK it looks like your index is actually a date str, I'll update my answer

Comment: It works. what's the difference between `ix` and `iloc`

Comment: [ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) is just a way for indexing using label values, `iloc` uses integer based indexing, as your index is str based I can't use `iloc` to slice this way, it would also work if you use `loc`